# Pegar texto da célula excel

Tags: java, microsoft-excel, apache-poi

Tenho uma aplicação que lê os dados do Excel, porém só consigo ler o valor da célula e não consigo ler o que a célula literalmente está mostrando.
Por exemplo: 
Aqui eu seleciono onde está a planilha e qual linha e qual coluna eu desejo pegar.
Na saída 1 mostra a fórmula e na saída 2 mostra o valor da célula.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém eu queria que na saída 2 aparecesse o que está sendo mostrado na planilha, por exemplo: "seg" e não "01-abr-2019".
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou usando a Framework Apache POI.
Segue código que utilizei para fazer o exemplo:

```
package newpackage;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.FormulaEvaluator;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory;

public class NewJFrame2 extends javax.swing.JFrame {

public NewJFrame2() {
    initComponents();
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    textoLinha = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    textoColuna = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    saida1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    textoCaminho = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    saida2 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    jButton1.setText("jButton1");
    jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jLabel1.setText("Linha");

    jLabel2.setText("Coluna");

    saida1.setEditable(false);

    jLabel3.setText("Caminho");

    saida2.setEditable(false);

    jLabel4.setText("Saida 1");

    jLabel5.setText("Saida 2");

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
    jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
    jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, false)
                        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(jLabel1)
                            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                            .addComponent(textoLinha))
                        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(jLabel2)
                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                            .addComponent(textoColuna, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 45, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 229, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 121, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                        .addComponent(jLabel4)
                        .addComponent(jLabel3)
                        .addComponent(jLabel5))
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addComponent(textoCaminho)
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, false)
                                .addComponent(saida2)
                                .addComponent(saida1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 121, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                            .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)))))
            .addContainerGap())
    );
    jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                .addComponent(textoLinha, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jLabel2)
                .addComponent(textoColuna, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jLabel3)
                .addComponent(textoCaminho, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(jLabel4)
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addComponent(jButton1)
                            .addContainerGap())
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                            .addComponent(jLabel5)
                            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))))
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(saida1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                    .addComponent(saida2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGap(0, 25, Short.MAX_VALUE))))
    );

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(0, 53, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    String caminhoPlanilha = textoCaminho.getText();
    String linha = textoLinha.getText();
    String coluna = textoColuna.getText();
    try (InputStream inp = new FileInputStream(caminhoPlanilha)) {
        Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(inp);
        FormulaEvaluator evaluator = wb.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();
        Sheet sheet1 = wb.getSheetAt(0);
        Row row = sheet1.getRow(Integer.parseInt(linha));
        Cell cell = row.getCell(Integer.parseInt(coluna));
        saida1.setText(cell.toString());
        saida2.setText(evaluator.evaluateInCell(cell).toString());
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame2.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}                                        

public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame2.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new NewJFrame2().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel5;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
private javax.swing.JTextField saida1;
private javax.swing.JTextField saida2;
private javax.swing.JTextField textoCaminho;
private javax.swing.JTextField textoColuna;
private javax.swing.JTextField textoLinha;
// End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Fiz a tela bem simples em um IDE, pois o que preciso saber é apenas a parte de ler da planilha de Excel.

Comment: Consegui uma classe que lê exatamente o que está sendo apresentado: XSSFExcelExtractor.
Mas não consigo posicionar ela em uma célula, ela lê todo o conteúdo da planilha, alguém pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não sei se é a melhor forma de resolver o problema, mas foi a forma com que eu consegui fazer.

Primeiro eu copiei minha planilha para outro `Workbook`:

```
Workbook wb1 = wb;
```

Depois passei por todos os valores da planilha recém criada e limpei o que não a linha e coluna selecionada:

```
Sheet s = wb1.getSheetAt(0);
        for (Row r : s) {
            for (Cell c : r) {
                if(c.getRowIndex() != Integer.parseInt(linha) || c.getColumnIndex() != Integer.parseInt(coluna))
                    c.setCellValue("");
            }
        }
```

Depois criei o `XSSFExcelExtractor` para a nova `Workbook` que acabei de criar:

```
XSSFExcelExtractor extractor = new XSSFExcelExtractor((XSSFWorkbook) wb1);
```

E por último peguei o valor do `XSSFExcelExtractor` substituindo os `\n`, os `\t` e o nome da planilha `s.getSheetName()` por vazio.

Segue o código de como ficou a nova ação do botão completo:

```
    String caminhoPlanilha = textoCaminho.getText();
    String linha = textoLinha.getText();
    String coluna = textoColuna.getText();
    try (InputStream inp = new FileInputStream(caminhoPlanilha)) {
        Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(inp);
        Sheet sheet1 = wb.getSheetAt(0);
        Row row = sheet1.getRow(Integer.parseInt(linha));
        Cell cell = row.getCell(Integer.parseInt(coluna));
        Workbook wb1 = wb;
        Sheet s = wb1.getSheetAt(0);
        for (Row r : s) {
            for (Cell c : r) {
                if(c.getRowIndex() != Integer.parseInt(linha) || c.getColumnIndex() != Integer.parseInt(coluna))
                    c.setCellValue("");
            }
        }
        saida1.setText(cell.toString());
        XSSFExcelExtractor extractor = new XSSFExcelExtractor((XSSFWorkbook) wb1);
        saida2.setText(extractor.getText().replace("\n", "").replace("\t", "").replace(s.getSheetName(), ""));
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame2.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

O resultado foi:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Se alguém achar uma forma mais simples de resolver poste aqui por favor.